# pytest command reports "Exception ignored" and "OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid"

Tags: python, threadpool

I found this error running pytest from the command line. All my tests still passed but it bothers me:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Pool.__del__ at 0x000001F5C70214E0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 271, in __del__
    self._change_notifier.put(None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 374, in put
    self._writer.send_bytes(obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 199, in send_bytes
    self._send_bytes(m[offset:offset + size])
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 279, in _send_bytes
    ov, err = _winapi.WriteFile(self._handle, buf, overlapped=True)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Running from PyCharm the error is completeley hidden.

What could be causing it?

I narrowed it down to a recently introduced test, and this fragment in particular:

```
    thread_pool = ThreadPool(pool_size)
    results = run_in_pool(function_list, thread_pool)
```

Answer (score 0):

ThreadPool is something of a poor relation in escaping the same scrutiny in documentation as the rest of python standard library.

In my code-under-test, I was creating it exactly as shown above. I never saw any complaints. Admittedly I'd never run it on a modern version of python before (today I'm using 3.11).

The preferred way of creating and managing a thread pool is with a context manager:

```
    with ThreadPool(pool_size) as thread_pool:
        results = run_in_pool(function_list, thread_pool)
```

[Jason Brownlee](https://superfastpython.com/threadpool-python/) has written a lot on this recently making his the de facto documentation for the class.

There are worse foot guns in the threading arsenal but `ThreadPool` needs more recognition.